# All microphones produce distorted sound as input

Tags: 18.04, microphone, audio-recording

My microphones used to work. However, at some point, perhaps after an update, they stopped. Now, instead of recording sound, they record a very distort version of that sound.

One was a Blue Yeti USB microphone attached via USB. Another was an XLR microphone attached via a mixer attached via USB. Usually they were not attached at the same time as one another.

I have verified these microphones do indeed work on other computers.

For the purposes of this post, I am trying to get the Blue Yeti mic to work.

The microphone is visible in "Settings > Input > Sound". It also gets levels. Applications recognize it, and as I said, it technically does record sound, it just distorts it heavily.

Here is the output of inxi -F, if that helps:

```
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GM204 High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel C600/X79 series High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 Blue Microphones Yeti Stereo Microphone driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-37-generic
```

Although it may be unrelated, it is worth noting that sound stopped working in Spotify and the default audio player in Linux around the time this stopped working.

Thanks.